# Changing Navigation Bar Color in Angular 5

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, angular5

I am using Angular 5 and Bootstrap 4 as my main front-end frameworks. I am using `fixed-top` bootstrap's nav bar. I am trying to change the background of that navbar when i scroll the window. That's why i tried using jquery but i am getting error i.e `$ is not defined`.
Here is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { 
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
      } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent"); 
      }
    });
  });
```

And this is my html code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor03" aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery library? Where's `.navbar-fixed-top` in HTML?

Comment: Try adding `<script src ="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the `head` of your **html** document

Comment: i have included jquery in my angular-cli.json

Answer (score 0):

If you replace `$(".navbar-fixed-top")` with `$(".navbar.fixed-top")`, then your code works like the following demo.

`$ is not defined` occurs when the jQuery library load failed. So you got to check your angular-cli.json again.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function() { 
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) { 
        // change the color from white to red to show the effect
        $(".navbar.fixed-top").css("background-color", "red");
      } else {
        $(".navbar.fixed-top").css("background-color", "transparent"); 
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
nav{
  height: 200vh; /* increase the height to make it scrollable*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor03" aria-controls="navbarColor03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor03">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```